# Can a stored procedure call truncate veiw table and enter data to the view table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, view

How to truncate a view table from a stored procedure in MySql.First tried executing the following query which failed what can be the error "TRUNCATE TABLE  tester ". Tester is a view table which I created from create view in mysql. I want to truncate the view table and enter new rows via a stored procedure.

Comment: A view is not a table. You can only truncate the table. But be sure, if you really want to do that! Read up about views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRUNCATE TABLE` does not work for views.

You can `DELETE FROM tester` and if the view is an updatable view it will apply the DELETE to the underlying table. But DELETE is slower than TRUNCATE, because DELETE has to do some bookkeeping to make sure it can be rolled back, whereas TRUNCATE cannot be rolled back.

You can instead do `TRUNCATE TABLE table_tester_is_based_on`, but as @fancyPants mentions, be sure this is what you want to do, because it will dispose of all the data in the base table. MySQL views don't store a *copy* of the base table, they are more like an alias for a query against the base table.